# Update user fields with Parse

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

How can I update a user field using Parse as backend? Here is the code:

```
for(ParseUser user : mFriends) {
    if (user.get("phoneNumber").toString().equals(result.substring(3))) {                                    
        user.increment("field");
        user.saveInBackground();
    }                               
}
```

The problem is that if I use the current user (the user who's using the application) instead of user, it works, but I want to update the field of another user.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to modify objects you do not own unless you set up public ACLs for that object.

Please see [Object-Level Access Control](https://parse.com/docs/data#security-objects) and [ParseACL](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseACL.html) for details.

In addition, you should probably look into [Relational Data](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-pointers) to better model your data. You really should not be modifying a direct field of another User object.

Comment: I see. But parse allows me to set up ACLs for records (so users). What if I want to set up an ACL for a specific column?